# in iPhone SDK How to change the color of BarButton Item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, interface-builder

How to change color of leftBarButtonItem of UIBarButtonItem in NavigationBar?

if I am trying to set image in bar button through interfaceBuilder it shows border on image in bar button so is there any specific size for image for bar button or how to set image with-out showing border in it ?

If I am adding BarButton dynamically it doesn"t appear while running  App
and if I am adding leftbarButton in xib only and connecting outlets then the leftbar button become visible but I am not able to assign customview view to it my ultimate goal is  to change the color of left bar buttton

Please Help and Suggest,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the bar buttom item with a custom view using `-[UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:]`. That way, you have all the control you want over the appearance.

Comment: Thanks for reply can You guide me more how to do it

Comment: You should ask a specific question (including things you have already tried) if you encounter a problem. I don't know where to begin.

Comment: I have tried with this code [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; addButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view1];    But i am not able to set bar button color to green Please Help                If I want to put image in barbutton item then what should be the size of image

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

You can set custom image for your bar button.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the colour you want to change, add the button to the bar and then set the tint colour of the bar (see docs on UINavigationBar or UIToolBar). This of course changes the bar colour as well as the button however, but it's good practice (UI consistency wise) to use the same colour for UIBarButtonItems and their bars especially if you're using out-of-the-box buttons.